# DL couldnt be added into the Owners Group in MOSS

Tags: 2007

Theres this **DL-GO-IT-SVPs & VPs** that would not pull up while trying to add to an owners Group whereas it will populate in Outlook i have verified that DL many times and tried typing it different ways with or without space but doesnt help, there are similar DL'S like **DL-GO-IT-ALL-IT Directors** getting populated in Sharepoint.This DL was not created recently it been there for long time when i say that i mean the Profile Sync is set to sync every one hour so thats also not a problem.

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a Distribution List is not seen as a proper AD group (The reason I believe is that it does not have a Security Identifier or SID).

Instead use an AD Domain Group and email enable it. This will get the group synchronised with the User Profile Service plus you can then use it to secure your resources!

Comment: Simon you are the man thank you i emailed my Email Admin and they i guess did what you told me..and it fixed the issue now i can add that DL into SharePoint.

Comment: glad to help out :)